# Determine if a grid (as a list of unique tuples) is full or sparse

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I need a quick way to determine if a grid is full or sparse. The grid (in my case of dimension 3) is represented as a list of **unique** 3-tuples $(x,y,z)$ (for context each tuple is stored as a record in a relational database). The list if of size $m$ and is known. Example (with a full grid) :

```
{1,1,1},
{1,1,2},
{1,2,1},
{1,2,2},
...
{3,2,1},
{3,2,2}
```

What I mean by a full grid is an Cartesian product of 3 sets $X,Y,Z$ of size $i,j,k$ respectively. However $X,Y,Z$ and $i,j,k$ are not given. **I only have the list of tuples.**

Let $i,j,k$ be the number of unique elements in each dimension in the list (in the example above, the unique elements would be $\{1,2,3\},\{1,2\},\{1,2\}$ so $i=3$ , $j=2$ and $k=2$).

With $m$ the number of tuples in the list, intuitively, I would say that
$$m=i\times j\times k$$ is a sufficient condition to say that the grid is full.

In other words, if the length of the list of tuples is equal to the product of the counts of unique elements in each dimension, then the grid must be full (and the list of tuples is indeed the Cartesian product of the unique elements).

This seems true and I cannot find any counter examples, however I would prefer to have a solid proof.

Sorry if the problem is not set properly. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Yes, if you have a set of $ijk$ distinct triples, all of which belong to $X\times Y\times Z$, then you have the entire Cartesian product.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I edited for clarity: I only have the list of tuples, $X,Y,Z$ are not given, they could be anything.

Comment: You have the cardinalities of $X,Y$, and $Z$, and that’s all that matters.

Comment: Is the minimum value of the various dimensions/fields required to be $1$ as here?

Answer (score 1):

To justify Brian Scott's answer (yes), let $A$ be the collection of all tuples that appear and let $B$ be the collection of all tuples in the box. Then $A\subseteq B$. If $|A|=|B|$ (they have the same size), then $A=B$, and the collection is exactly the box. This works whenever the two sets are finite. You can rigorously justify this using induction.